Proxmox + Docker - Cannot pull or search images - DNS issues?
Over the last few weeks I have been scratching my head trying to get Docker (and ultimately Portainer) running on an LXC in Proxmox. My setup is as follows:

Proxmox Virtual Environment 8.2.4 (192.168.0.119)

Hardwired into router (192.168.0.1) --> Hardwired into modem (192.168.1.1); Router in DHCP mode also providing DNS.


Proxmox is running:

VM with Home Assistant OS (via the appropriate Proxmox VE Helper-Script)

LXC (Ubuntu) with Tailscale for remote access - including subnet routing (I plan to expose the Portainer LXC via this LXC as well)


Everything works fine until I try to spin up a new LXC and install Docker on it (both using the Proxmox VE Helper-Scripts and manually). At that point the DNS resolution breaks (somewhat) and Docker can not login, search images, or pull images. In addition dig google.com no longer works, whereas dig google.com +tcp does. Ping also works as expected. These symptoms are the same regardless of whether I use the host, LXC or the VM.
In troubleshooting I have:

Done a complete reinstall of the Proxmox VE
Disabled DNS from Tailscale using --accept-dns=false see: https://tailscale.com/kb/1235/resolv-conf
Reconfigured host DNS servers to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8
Reconfigured LXC DNS servers to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8, including removing the symlink between their resolv-conf and the host
Confirmed above dig commands are working on other machines on the same network, they are also able to pull images from the Docker repo as expected

Anyone with experience running Proxmox VE and Docker who can help me navigate the troubleshooting steps? I suspect it may be related to firewall settings and the Docker internal IP addresses? But very new to Docker in general and unaware of how networking around pulling images works.

"dig google.com no longer works, whereas dig google.com +tcp does." UDP port 53 blocked by firewall configuration at some level?

@telcoM, thanks. I have also disabled firewall at all levels temporarily just to check and I am still getting timeouts of dig. However, ping resolves the domain correctly. I am unfamiliar with networking troubleshooting so grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

This smells like it might be related to a subnet CIDR range colusion somhow: either LXC or docker setting up something. I had something that appeared a lot like this, with a two tier host network (192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1). Docker then created a subnet that collided with the gateway's 192.168.1.1. This may not be your problem, but do check you know every subnet used by LXC and Docker and ensure there are no collisions between them.
